# 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: list, python-2.7

I want to remove 362968 from below list-

list=[362976,362974,362971,362968,362969]

code-

```
list.remove(362968)
```

I am getting error: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'

Actual code -

```
def matchmaker():
exportersfree = exporters[:]
engaged  = {}
exprefers2 = copy.deepcopy(exprefers)
imprefers2 = copy.deepcopy(imprefers)
while exportersfree:
    exporter = exportersfree.pop(0)
    exporterslist = exprefers2[exporter]
    importer = exporterslist.pop(0)
    match = engaged.get(importer)
    if not match:
        # impo's free
        engaged[importer] = exporter #both parties are added to the engaged list
        importerslist = imprefers2[importer]
        for z in range (importerslist.index(exporter)-1):
                    importerslist.index(exporter)
                    exprefers2[importerslist[z]].remove(importer)
        del importerslist[0:(importerslist.index(exporter)-1)]

    else
            engaged[importer] = exporter
            if exprefers2[match]:
                # Ex has more importers to try
                exportersfree.append(match)

return engaged
```

Comment: del list[3], try this

Comment: I would prefer to delete the item by quoting the item itself.

Comment: Hmm, this is not true. The 2 lines of code work fine in Python2.7. Also change your list name to something other than `list` since that's the list constructor.

Comment: @CristiFati I have my list name as `exprefers2[importerslist[z]]` and exprefers2 is a dictionary and importerslist is a  list

Comment: or is it possible that `list='[362976,362974,362971,362968,362969]'`? Notice the quotes surrounding the square brackets.

Comment: Please add some more code, (how the dictionary looks like), the line that throws the error because is kind of difficult to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Add 2 lines: `print importerslist[z]` and `print exprefers2[importerslist[z]]` before `exprefers2[importerslist[z]].remove(importer)`. Maybe not all the `exprefers2` values are lists. Also `importerslist.index(exporter)` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without additional code to really debug, exprefers2is clearly a dict of strings; however, if you really want to delete it. You can cast the string to a list, or eval the value to convert it into a list, then use list.remove

```
import ast

list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list.remove(5)
print list
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]


#Data Structure you most likely have
import_list = [1, 2]
exprefers2 = {1: "abc", 2: "xyz"}
print exprefers2[import_list[1]]
#xyz


#Or need to eval the string of a list
import_list = [1, 2]
exprefers2 = {1: u'[ "A","B","C" , " D"]', 2: u'[ "z","x","y" , " y"]'}
exprefers2[import_list[1]] = ast.literal_eval(exprefers2[import_list[1]])
exprefers2[import_list[1]].remove("y")
print exprefers2[import_list[1]]
#['z', 'x', ' y']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it in this way then, name your list "a".

```
 a = [362976,362974,362971,362968,362969]
     a.remove(362968) 
     print a
```

Comment: I have my list name as `exprefers2[importerslist[z]]` and exprefers2 is a dictionary and importerslist is a list

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to check if the X has been changed.
x = [1, 40, 33, 20]
x.remove(33)
print (x)